# JSP deployment without war file

Tags: jsp

The thing is that I do not want to replace an entire web app contained in "war" file just because there needs to be a change in a single JSP file. So is it possible to deploy JSP pages on to a Web Server without packaging it into the "war" file? If so then on which Web Servers can this be done (and how)?

---

Actually, I am looking for a solution like classic ASP or PHP. In these environments, there is no need for a specific XML configuration file, and they do not need to be packaged in a WAR file that gets expanded to a directory. If I were to change a single ASP/PHP page then I only need to upload that to the Web Server and they have a simple directory layout. Is that possible with JSP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if the container is configured to expand the WAR on disk (most by default do), then you can just replace the file directly in the expanded WAR folder. If the container doesn't support hotdeploy (most production server configs don't, at least if they are managed by a very good server admin), then you also need to restart the server.

---

**Update**: if you don't want to deploy with a WAR, but just want to manually create the deployment files, then just create the necessary folders/files in the deploy folder directly. In [Tomcat 7.0](http://tomcat.apache.org) for example, which is a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, just create a new subfolder in its `/webapps` folder.

```
Tomcat
 |-- bin
 |-- conf
 |-- lib
 |-- logs
 |-- temp
 |-- webapps
 |    `-- jazz
 |         `-- page.jsp
 `-- work
```

It'll be available as `http://localhost:8080/jazz/page.jsp`.

If you want it to be on domain root like so `http://localhost:8080/page.jsp`, then rename the subfolder to `ROOT` (yes, uppercased). You can just delete/rename the existing one which contains the Tomcat default homepage.

Comment: Are you aware of any servers that may allow JSP without the "war" files. I was looking to simplify the process to the level like ASP or PHP.

Comment: Any of them do by default. Just create/put the expanded WAR file structure in the deploy folder yourself. Only hotdeploy is a different matter, most of them are by default configured to do so, but in production this is often turned off. In Tomcat, for example, just create a new subfolder in its `/webapps` folder and put the JSPs straight in there. It'll be available by http://localhost:8080/subfoldername/some.jsp

Comment: I want to remove the "war" files  and the configuration files out the picture completely. I want the directory layout to be very simple, like ASP/PHP.

Comment: As said, just create the expanded WAR file structure in the deploy folder yourself. This doesn't require a WAR file to be placed. If you're using a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, this also doesn't require a `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file. So you basically need to create only one subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the Web Servers support `Hot deployment and dynamic reloading`. Which `extracts the WAR file within the server working directory`. You can `replace your Modified JSP there` to get picket at runtime.

Look here  for Hot Deployment on different servers:

- [Websphere](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/trun_app_hotupgrade.html)
- [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html)

Comment: So is there no option to create the web apps excluding the "war" files?

Comment: I did not get your comment. You can just find the working directory where the WAR is extracted and put replace your JSP there. Note: This will work only if Hot Deployment is supported by the web server. By the way, which Web Server you are using.

Comment: I want to remove the "war" files out the picture completely. I want the directory layout to be very simple, like ASP/PHP.