# page loading got extremely slow after replacing .jar file in lib directory

Tags: apache, jsp, servlets, jboss

I'm a noob here, and I really need your advice.

I'm working on jBoss/Struts environment, and faced a trouble.
One day I simply replaced cos.jar file in .war/WEB-INF/lib directory with the recent one.
I don't remember whether the WAS was down or not at that time.

Symptom:
**Page loading speed got extremely slow**. Sometimes randomly as fast as before, but usually unacceptibly slow. So I monitored WAS' log then found that connection between WAS and DB is just OK.
Seems that the bottleneck is at the entry point(servlet) or output-related part.

When I do **netstat -ano | grep 80**, the list shows a lot of **CLOSE_WAIT** s in keepalive states.

More seriously, **it seems like the entire server hangs up for a moment**, disconnecting ftp or telnet.

There was **no lack of memory or hard disk storage**.
Someone suggested me that too large apache log file can cause such problem (not yet tried)

Environment:
Centos 5.4 / Apache / jBoss 5.1GA / cos.jar (1.1 -> 1.4 -> 1.1)

I would greatly appreciate you if you help me.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace a jar file in `WEB-INF/lib` of an `Web Wpplication`, the server has to do either one of these things:

- Restart the web application
- Reconstruct the class loader

I would say most of the servers will be `restarting the web application` because the jar might `contain a modified Servlet` which has to be reloaded.

**Note:** The above statement will apply only if [Hot Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996977/jsp-deployment-without-war-file/10997149#10997149) is enabled.

Comment: I was running CentOs on VMWare on a windows server. And there were several failed connection on parent OS, I mean windows. Thus all problem was not about WAS. Sorry for silly question, but appreciate for your kind answer.